# Visualizing various layers through commmand line/automation on QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, visualisation

I am new to QGIS but I would like to visualise spatial data. I have a huge amount of layers and I want to take a snapshot of all these different layers with a script. I was hoping I could select which layer I want and maybe configure something from each layer through the command line but I am not so sure how to go about it. Actually, I am not so sure what tools QGIS offers for this task or if it offers any at all? Maybe I should look at other tools than QGIS?

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to use pyqgis http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins_pyqgis.html

Comment: Hi yes thanks, seems like pygis is the way to go but can I generate snapshots from it similar to how qgis.bat offers taking a snapshot?

Comment: you can run it via a windows .bat or linux bash file